# Solving an infinite sum of incomplete gamma with integer parameter

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function, pochhammer-symbol

In trying to simplify a distribution function, I stumbled upon this infinite sum involving an (upper) Gamma function. I would believe it can be simplified further, but can't find how.

$$1-
\frac{(1-\rho^2)^{v/4}}{\Gamma(\frac{v}{2})}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(
\frac{ (\frac{\rho}{2})^{2k} }{k! \;(\frac{v+2}{4})_k}
\; \Gamma\Big(\frac{v}{2}+2k, \alpha \Big)
\right)
$$

in which $v$ is integer and a multiple of 2 (so that $v/2$ is also an integer), $\rho$ is a population correlation ($-1\le \rho\le 1$) and $(\frac{v+2}{4})_k$ is the Pochhammer function, that is, $\Gamma\Big((v+2)/4+k \Big)/ \Gamma(\Big(v+2)/4\Big)$.

I tried series expansion of the incomplete Gamma function, to no avail. I also tried replacing the Pochhammer function with various expansion, in particular $(-1)^k k! \binom{\frac{1}{4} (-v-2)}{k}$. I am pretty sure the result will involve another `special function`, but this is fine, I mostly desire a solution which can be expressed without an infinite sum.

Comment: If $$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^{2 k} \Gamma \left(\frac{1+n}{2}\right) \Gamma (2 k+n,\alpha )}{\Gamma (1+k) \Gamma \left(k+\frac{1+n}{2}\right)}=\int_{\alpha }^{\infty } e^{-t} t^{-1+n} \,
   _0F_1\left(;\frac{1+n}{2};t^2 x^2\right) \, dt$$,**Mathematica** can find closed-form only for: `n=...-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8...`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I have MMA 10.0 and it cannot find a solution. Can you share it please?

Comment: For what `n` do you want a solution ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Both odd and even n > 2. I do not mind having a closed-form solution for even and one involving an infinite sum for odd ns. That seems unavoidable!

Comment: MMA code: for n=4, `-((3 E^-\[Alpha] (2 x (4 x^2 (-2 + \[Alpha]) - \[Alpha]) Cosh[
      2 x \[Alpha]] + (1 + 16 x^4 \[Alpha] - 
       4 x^2 (3 + \[Alpha])) Sinh[2 x \[Alpha]]))/(
 8 x^3 (1 - 4 x^2)^2))` .

Comment: for n=-4,`(1/(96 \[Alpha]^4))E^-\[Alpha] (4 (6 + \[Alpha] (-2 + \[Alpha] (1 - \
\[Alpha] + 4 x^2 (1 + \[Alpha])))) Cosh[2 x \[Alpha]] - 
   E^\[Alpha] (1 - 
      4 x^2)^2 \[Alpha]^4 (2 ExpIntegralEi[(-1 + 2 x) \[Alpha]] + 
      2 ExpIntegralEi[-((1 + 2 x) \[Alpha])] + Log[1/(-1 - 2 x)] - 
      Log[-1 - 2 x] + 2 Log[1 - 2 x] + Log[1/(-1 + 2 x)] - 
      Log[-1 + 2 x] + 2 Log[1 + 2 x]) + 
   8 x \[Alpha] (-6 + \[Alpha] (2 + (-1 + 4 x^2) \[Alpha])) Sinh[
     2 x \[Alpha]])`

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed all the problem is related to the incomplete gamma function.

To simplify notation, let $x=\frac \rho 2$ and $n=\frac v2$ and write the summation as
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2 k} \,\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (k+1)\, \Gamma\left(k+\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}\Gamma (2 k+n,\alpha )$$

*Assuming* that we could use the series expansion of
$\Gamma (2 k+n,\alpha )$ around $\alpha=0$, we should have

$$S_n=\frac {\Gamma (n)}{\left(1-4 x^2\right)^{\frac n2}}+\sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m \frac{\alpha^{(n+m)}}{m! \,(n+m)}\,
   _1F_2\left(\frac{n+m}{2};\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{n+m+2}{2};x^2 \alpha
   ^2\right)$$  For odd values of $m$, the summand can write in terms of Bessel functions of the first kind.

**Edit**

For odd values of $m=2p+1$, consider

$$G_p=\frac{\alpha ^{2 p+n+1}}{(2 p+1)! (2 p+n+1)} \,
   _1F_2\left(\frac{2p+n+1}{2};\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{2p+n+3}{2};x^2 \alpha ^2\right)$$

$$G_0=\frac{1}{2} \alpha ^{\frac{n+1}{2}} x^{-\frac{n+1}{2}} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) I_{\frac{n+1}{2}}(2 x \alpha )$$
$$G_1=\frac{n-1}{48} \alpha ^{\frac{n+3}{2}} x^{-\frac{n+3}{2}} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right) \left((n+1) I_{\frac{n+3}{2}}(2 x \alpha )+2 \alpha  x I_{\frac{n+5}{2}}(2 x
   \alpha )\right)$$

Comment: Hello;  (i) to match the results of computations, it seems necessary to subtract the sum, not add it. Is it correct? (ii) did you meant "for odd values of $v$"?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am missing a step there. How can the summand be replaced by a Bessel function? Without $_1F_2$, the sum seems fairly close to the series expansion of the Bessel of the first kind, but with this hypergeometric function, I don't see how to do the change..

Comment: @DenisCousineau. Have a look at the edit